# Python C equivalence of this ternary operator

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I want to program this function from C to Python but the condition on the return is hard to convert:

In C:

```
int pos(int b) {
    char *r = strchr(a, b);
    return r?(r - a):-1;
}
```

Here what I tried:

```
def pos(b) :
    r = alphabet[a.rfind(b):]
    return r if (r - len(a)) else -1
```

The r variable is the same but the problem is the ternary operator.
So of course, it doesn't do the same work :/
Can you help me?

Comment: if you are looking for a ternary operator in python this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What was unclear about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python ternary operator goes in a different order than the C ternary operator. The C ternary operator is in the form:

```
condition ? expr_if_true : expr_if_false
```

Whereas the Python version of this is in the form:

```
expr_if_true if condition else expr_if_false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return r?(r - a):-1;
```

Is the same as

```
if (r != NULL) return r - a;
else           return -1;
```

Comment: In the C code, a is a char and I dont know how to substrate strings in python

Comment: @Alpacah `a` is a `char *`, so `r-a` is the index of `a` in `r`.